# In GWT how to change listbox dropdown list size alone?

Tags: gwt

I Have a listbox with fixed size, width = 200px, but the content in the listbox size is more.So I want only the **dropdown** width to be increased.How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried min-width: 200px and not width: 200px. This way the min size is 200px but it will grow if larger.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set the `listbox` style to the width you want , and the option dropdowns will automatically adjust to option element size (alternatively you can use the .gwt-ListBox CSS class to define any CSS styling),

```
ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
listBox.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(200, Unit.PX);
listBox.addItem("AAA");
listBox.addItem("AAAAAA");
listBox.addItem("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
listBox.addItem("AAADDDDDDDDD");
```

[image]
[image]

If you want to style the drop down elements you can do so via adding a class to your list box and then styling the options,

```
listBox.addStyleName("myListBox");
```

Css

```
.myListBox { 
width:200px; 
} 
.myListBox option { 
width:500px; 
}
```

**UPDATE**

There is a way

```
    listBox.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event)
        {
            listBox.addStyleName("expand");
        }
    });

    listBox.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onBlur(BlurEvent event)
        {
            listBox.addStyleName("normal");
        }
    });
    listBox.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onChange(ChangeEvent event)
        {
            listBox.addStyleName("normal");
        }
    });

.normal
{
width=200px;
}

.expand
{
width : auto;
}
```

In simple words set width to auto when viewing options else set it to default.

Comment: If we give listbox a width, it will be fixed to that size and the options will also fit to that width. The CSS with options is also not working :(

Comment: if you restrict the ListBox to a width say 200px the options do not get restricted to 200px they take a width of maximum length option found. check my screen shots.

Comment: No Onkar, They are restricted

Comment: can you please share your code for me it is not restricting i cant understand why it is doing it for you! i have the screenshots of the actual working GWT aplication

Comment: Its working fine with chrome, but not in IE. Any suggestions?